# Iterating over a json object, then adding the results to an array

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm iterating over a JSON object, then adding each result I get to an array but for each result that gets added to the array, they array is then cleared then it moves down the list of results.

Here's what I mean:
[image]

Here's the code I used to get this issue:

```py
for e in loadedJson['posts']['entities']:
  print(e)
  titles = []
  titles.append(e)
  print(titles)
```

Comment: you are clearing the array on this line `titles = []` in each iteration. So what's the problem?

Comment: Move `titles=[]` before the loop, that's it

Comment: Oh, yeah sorry I completely didn't realise what I did. Thanks!

Comment: The array is cleared because you say so. Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to move titles outside the loop

```
titles = []
for e in loadedJson['posts']['entities']:
  print(e)
  titles.append(e)
print(titles)
```